# Diffuse irradiance map : confusion about photometric vs radiometric units

Tags: physically-based, photometric

I have spent the longest amount of time just taking the terminology for granted & have only just recently started studying or at least trying to understand the difference between radiometric and photometric units.

It has recently dawned on me that most PBR implementations (in realtime rendering and video game engines such as Frostbite, UE4, Unity or even Filament) use the term **diffuse irradiance** *(radiometric unit)* yet they use photometric units for the rest of their lighting pipeline, analytic lights & output **luminance** *(photometric unit)* to their render target / output surface.

Is the use of the term **diffuse irradiance** actually correct or am I right in thinking the correct term should really be **diffuse illuminance**, since the term is usually generated from a cubemap rendered through the same lighting pipeline and expressed in luminance, or a HDR image?

Thanks in advance,